# How to run analysis on a 16M row table faster

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, explain

I have two tables `students` with 6k records and `transactions` with 16M records.

I have a query similar to this:

```
select section, count(s.students) from students as s
where upper(name) in 
    (select upper(name) from transactions as t 
        where (length(transaction_id) < 43 or 
            lower(transaction_name) = 'NA' or 
            lower(transaction_type) = 'food')
            and upper(name) not in ('JOHN DOE')) 
group by section 
order by section asc
```

The query plan for this is similar to below:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=2828274.40..2828291.32 rows=6 width=12) (actual time=101295.078..101301.568 rows=6 loops=1)
   Group Key: section
   ->  Sort  (cost=2828274.40..2828280.02 rows=2247 width=25) (actual time=101294.727..101300.274 rows=2414 loops=1)
         Sort Key: section
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 285kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=2827697.15..2828149.32 rows=2247 width=25) (actual time=101278.618..101292.861 rows=2414 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: ((s.name)::text = (t.name)::text)
               ->  Seq Scan on students s  (cost=0.00..412.16 rows=5716 width=25) (actual time=0.007..2.887 rows=5720 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=2827669.07..2827669.07 rows=2247 width=21) (actual time=101278.578..101278.578 rows=2445 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 159kB
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2827646.60..2827669.07 rows=2247 width=21) (actual time=101274.023..101276.849 rows=2445 loops=1)
                           Group Key: (t.name)::text
                           ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..2804729.14 rows=9166982 width=21) (actual time=97.170..100735.029 rows=449343 loops=1)
                                 Workers Planned: 2
                                 Workers Launched: 2
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transactions t  (cost=0.00..1887030.94 rows=3819576 width=21) (actual time=130.428..100660.838 rows=149781 loops=3)
                                       Filter: (((name)::text <> 'JOHN DOE'::text) AND ((length((transaction_id)::text) < 23) OR (lower((transaction_type)::text) = 'food'::text)) OR OR (lower((transaction_name)::text) = 'NA'::text))))
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 4897554
 Planning time: 10.027 ms
 Execution time: 101301.982 ms
```

Comment: How can `lower(transaction_name) = 'NA'` - ever be true? Should that be `= 'na'`?

Comment: If you run this query repeatedly, which parameters are going to change between runs?  And if you don't run repeatedly, why isn't 101 seconds fast enough for a one-time thing?  Also, it looks you manually anonymized you EXPLAIN output, and kind of mangled it.

Comment: Please turn on track_io_timing, and do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Answer (score 0):

All your time is spent in a sequential scan that discards almost all the rows it scans. Unfortunately you have an `OR` in there, so the best you can do is to create three indexes and hope for a "bitmap or" of the three index scans:

```
CREATE INDEX transactions_type_idx ON transactions (lower(transaction_type::text));
CREATE INDEX transactions_name_idx ON transactions (lower(transaction_name::text));
CREATE INDEX transactions_id_length_idx ON transactions (length(transaction_id::text));
```